# What does "you'll be in your whack" mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms, british-english

Another colorful expression from that British movie I mentioned earlier.  The context of the quote here is that there are these guys trying to smuggle ecstasy pills, and there's another guy hosting their meeting in exchange for a below-the-table bribe, though he's not directly involved himself.  The host is anxious and wants them to move on quickly from the spot he's providing, as he's a civilian -- he doesn't "want to get nicked."  One of the smugglers retorts back to him, "Don't worry, you'll be in your whack", in what sounds like a Cockney English accent.

So my questions are: What does this phrase mean, exactly? What does the *whack* add to the meaning?  Is it common amongst certain types of British English speakers?

Comment: I have only ever heard the word as synonym for kill or something bad. He wacked him - that is whack!

Comment: What film is it? It might be able to help us answer you question.

Comment: @sturner The name of the film is _Layer Cake_, starring Daniel Craig.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Green's Dictionary of Slang has *in whack (with)* as taking equal shares, and also *whack* as a share or portion. I think that is what is meant here; "you'll get your share".

Among the numerous other meanings of *whack* is also a prison sentence, and the phrase *cop your whack* means "to get your just deserts". Perhaps this sentence is a play on the multiple meanings; "you'll get your share of the good things - and the bad".